# Rename URL from the htaccess file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I would like to rename, not redirect a number of URL's I have on my website using the *.htaccess* file:
from `http://siteaddress.com/?chapter=1` to `http://siteaddress.com/about`.

As I'm quite new to dabbling with the *.htaccess* file and I can't afford to brake anything, how would I be able to achieve this in a safe and simple manor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?chapter=1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /about? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^about/?$ /?chapter=1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

With above in place now when you try to visit `http://site.com/about` it will internally forward your request to: `http://site.com/?chapter=1` while not changing the URL in the browser (no redirect). When you visit `http://site.com/?chapter=1` it will be externally redirected to `http://site.com/about` .

Comment: I placed the script you provided in my htaccess file @anubhava but when I visit `http://siteaddress.com/?chapter=1` the URL stays the same, rather than displaying it as `http://siteaddress.com/about`.

Comment: Oh so you want reverse redirection as well. You question `to rename, not redirect a number of URL's` was implying something else. I will edit my answer to do reverse redirection as well.

Comment: It's definitely getting there @anubhava...Thank you for all your help.  It renames the `/?chapter=1` to `/about` which is exactly what I was after but it can't find the page (404 error).

Comment: 2nd rule; `RewriteRule ^about/?$ /?chapter=1 [L,NC,QSA]` will internally forward it back to: `/?chapter=1`